# Is externally visible checkbox not being checked when customer sends an email to case

Tags: email2case

When an email comes into an existing case, the `incoming` checkbox is marked as true but the `is externally visible` checkbox is not marked as true even though the email came from outside Salesforce.

The documentation does not mention what conditions must be met for marking this field as true. From my reports, I can see that when emails are sent to the case that do not include the case contact email then `is externally visible` is not marked as true. Is this standard behaviour or is this by design in my Salesforce org?